# Multiple string substitution for tuples in Python

Tags: python

I want to substitute multiple string elements in tuples with replace set.

```
from itertools import chain

old = [('Jack','Mike'),('Rosa','Mike'),('Pete','Jake'),('Beth','Jake')]
uniquelist = list(dict.fromkeys([ i for i in chain(*old)]))
replaceset = [("a" + str(new),old) for new,old in enumerate(uniquelist)]
```

`replaceset` is:

```
[('a0', 'Jack'), ('a1', 'Mike'), ('a2', 'Rosa'), ('a3', 'Pete'), ('a4', 'Jake'), ('a5', 'Beth')]
```

This is the output I want from `old`.

> [('a0','a1'),('a2','a1'),('a3','a4'),('a5','a4')]

Is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: This would be trivial if you made replaceset a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am going to assume here that you are working with Python 3.7+ and that maintaining order is important to you.**

Just convert `replaceset` into a dict and recreate `old` with a list-comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

old = [('Jack','Mike'),('Rosa','Mike'),('Pete','Jake'),('Beth','Jake')]
uniquelist = list(dict.fromkeys([ i for i in chain(*old)]))
#replaceset = [("a" + str(new),old) for new,old in enumerate(uniquelist)]
replaceset = {old:"a" + str(new) for new, old in enumerate(uniquelist)}

res = [tuple(replaceset[name] for name in sub) for sub in old]
print(res)  # [('a0', 'a1'), ('a2', 'a1'), ('a3', 'a4'), ('a5', 'a4')]
```

---

As a sidenote,

```
uniquelist = dict.fromkeys(chain(*old))
```

would also work and make you more efficient too.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for letting me know this way:)

Comment: Also, rather than using `dict.fromkeys`, consider using `set(chain(*old))` (or `frozenset`), which expresses the intent better.

Comment: `[ i for i in chain(*old)]` looks wierd. Doesn't `chain(*old)` work? at any rate it's better to do `list(chain(*old))`

Comment: @OliverW. with `set` it does not work because sets do not preserve insertion order. I believe OP wants insertion order on top of *repetition detection*.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `chain(*old)` does work; see sidenote. we cannot use `list` here however since that would not get rid of the duplicate values and the `dict` call will overwrite them later.

Comment: That wasn’t specified. Additionally `dict.fromkeys` does not preserve insertion order either prior to Python 3.6.

Comment: @OliverW. It was not but if we disregard that we will be getting a different result every time we run it, so I think it is safe to assume. As far as the second part of your comment goes, you are right; I have edited my answer.